# How to scrape data from a gchart using BS or selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, beautifulsoup

I'm looking to pull data from a chart that is viewable when you hover over it with your mouse but does not appear on the source code. Is there any way to extract this? I'm new to this but havent been able to find a discussion on this anywhere so far. It seems like a job for selenium or maybe something cool I've never heard of.

The code below relates to the cannabinoids section, which is the area I'm interested in, along with the terpenes section which has the same issue.

https://www.dinafem.org/en/amnesia-cbd/

```
<div id="product-cannabinoids-chart-wrapper"> <div data-chart_id="product_cannabinoids" class="auto-gchart" id="product_cannabinoids_chart"></div> </div> <form data-chart_id="product_cannabinoids" class="auto-gchart-filters" style="display: none;"> <input type="hidden" name="product_sku" value="0003142"/> </form>
```

Comment: First you need to hover over that elements, but currently I don't know how to locate them! It's interesting.

Comment: ah, so there is a "hover" command? That's helpful to know - definitely a step in the right direction! It feels to me like the "value" is getting plugged in somewhere which returns the whole chart, but I'm a novice here and don't really know how all this javascript stuff works.

Comment: Yup. If I could locate these elements with `xpath` I would give you a comprehensive solution, but currently I can't. I just asked separated question about this issue here. Hope someone will help us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those tables come from a `POST` request. You can mimic that with pure `requests`.

Here's how:

```
import json

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.dinafem.org/en/amnesia-cbd/?PageSpeed=noscript"

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) "
                  "AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) "
                  "Chrome/90.0.4430.85 Safari/537.36",
    "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
}

with requests.Session() as connection:
    product_sku = BeautifulSoup(
        connection.get(url).text,
        "html.parser",
    ).find("input", {"name": "product_sku"})["value"]

    chart_ids = ["product_cannabinoids", "product_terpenes"]

    payload = {
        "action": "get_gchart_data",
        "filters": f"product_sku={product_sku}",
    }

    charts = []
    for chart_id in chart_ids:
        payload.update({"chart_id": chart_id})
        charts.append(connection.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload).json())

print(json.dumps(charts[0], indent=2))
```

Output:

```
{
  "error": 0,
  "chart_id": "product_cannabinoids",
  "data": [
    [
      "Cannabinoid",
      "(%)"
    ],
    [
      "CBD",
      11.64
    ],
    [
      "THC",
      7.37
    ],
    [
      "CBC",
      0.7
    ],
    [
      "CBG",
      0.46
    ],
    [
      "THCV",
      0.04
    ],
    [
      "CBN",
      0.01
    ]
  ],
  "debug": {
    "total": 20.220000000000002
  }
}
```

You can even plot that to get a *real-like* chart that's on the website.

Add this to your imports:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

and then put this:

```
data = [i[1] for i in charts[1]["data"]]
info = [i[0] for i in charts[1]["data"]]
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 7))
plt.pie(data, labels=info)
plt.show()
```

To get this:

[image]

Comment: You're too much. Thanks again for your generosity. Love your Lovecraft quote. Reminds me of Plato's Allegory of the Cave. Keep being awesome, showing people the light, etc.

Answer (score 2):

To do this with Selenium first you need to hover over the required chart rectangle.
For example, if you are looking for the second rectangle it is located by `(//div[@data-chart_id='product_cannabinoids']//*[name()='g']//*[name()='g']//*[name()='rect' and contains(@width,'108')])[2]`
To hover over element you can use following method:

```
public void hoverOverElement(By.xpath(xpath)){
        action = new Actions(driver);
        webElement = driver.findElement(element);
        action.moveToElement(webElement).build().perform();
    }
```

where `xpath` is as presented above.
Now you can locate the appeared tooltip element located by `//*[name()='g' and @class='google-visualization-tooltip']` and extract it's value.

Comment: What I was trying to say in [your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67258112/what-is-python-equivalent-for-java-selenium-expected-condition-numberofelementst) before you deleted the entire thing after accusing me of I don't know what... was that I look at each question individually. I don't do python but I can look at the docs and generally figure things out. If I can google and look in the docs and find the answer in 60s or less, I think that easily qualifies as, "This question does not show any research effort". Thus the downvote.

Comment: If you don't want your questions downvoted, spend some time doing research on your own and see if you can find the answer. ... and asking a question, having people spend time on providing an answer and then deleting the whole thing is a display of poor behavior.

Comment: I would never delete a question with answer, but I see it is totally unfair. I spend a lot of time here in the last period and I see that most questions here are of very low efforts, much less than mine.

Comment: Oh... but you did... [What is Python equivalent for Java Selenium expected condition numberOfElementsToBeMoreThan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67258112/what-is-python-equivalent-for-java-selenium-expected-condition-numberofelementst)?
... and you switched your user name.